# Python loop slowdown

Tags: python, arduino

So I am trying to read data from an arduino board through serial. Currently I have it saving the data for eventual graphing in hopefully close to real time. As of right now I am getting a slowdown in my execution when I try to read more than ~150 at one time. I am not completely sure why. It does not seem to be a lack of memory because it barely uses any. The serial connection is almost instantaneous. Python is not my most used language so I apologize if it is something stupid.

My python code is below.

```
import serial
import matplotlib as plt
import time
from time import sleep as zzz
import csv

ser = serial.Serial(2, 9600)

startTime = time.clock()
line = ser.readline()
dataInital = [float(val) for val in line.split()][0]

timeList = []*12000
dataList = []*12000
timeList.append(startTime)
dataList.append(dataInital)

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:

    testFile = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    #testFile.writerow([dataInital, "%f" % (startTime)])

    userInput = input("enter q to quit, r to read: ")

    while userInput != 'q':
        n = 1
        if userInput == 'r':
            n = int(input("How many seconds do you want to read? "))
        for i in range(1, n):
            ser.write(b'1')
            line = ser.readline()
            timeList.append(time.clock())
            data = [float(val) for val in line.split()][0]
            dataList.append(data)
            print(data)
            zzz(1)
    userInput = input("enter q to quit, r to read: ")

    finalTime = time.clock()
    timeList.append(finalTime)
    testFile.writerows(zip(dataList, timeList))
    testFile.writerow(["No data",timeList[-1]])
    print("%f:%f" % (startTime, finalTime))
```

Comment: what do you think `timeList = []*12000` is doing?

Comment: I would assume it is initializing an empty list of size 12k, that's a leftover remnant of when I had timeList = [0]*12000. I tried to use a counter variable and put everything I to the list that way but I was still experiencing a small amount of lag using larger numbers.

Comment: that is not how python works, you simply `needtimeList = []`.

Comment: OK, that was what I started with. However, that still gives me the same issue.

Comment: `[]` is the same thing as `[]*1000`

Comment: what is `150` in ~150 at one time.?

Comment: n = 150 in that loop

Comment: How bad is the slowdown?  When `n` is 150, we would expect it to take about 150 seconds, but it actually takes...?

Comment: It takes 5-10 seconds for one second operation. Somewhere after 100, but before 150. Sometimes I just C-c out of the program because it seems like it just hangs for far too long.

Comment: on average if I pick ten and quit immediately I get ~12-13 seconds. I get ~52 seconds when n = 50. When n = 100, it takes about 103-104 seconds. When n = 150, it looks like there are some slowdowns but my final time is consistent at ~154. However, at n = 200 this is where it becomes obvious, the final time is ~524. If i run it as n = 100, and then n=100 again I see an improvement as the total time is ~473 seconds, but that is still double what I would expect. I do not know if I will need hundreds of data points, but I would like to be able to handle them if need be.